# Prove if $n^2$ is even, then $n^2$ is divisible by 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am working on this question

> Prove for every integer n if $n^2$ is even, then $n^2$ is divisible by 4.

prove  by contradiction

**Proof:**

Since there exists an integer $n$ such that $n^2$ is even, and $n^2$ is not divisible by 4,

when $n$ is odd integer, we have $n = 2k + 1$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$,

then $n^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1$, because $n^2$ is odd which is a contradiction;

when $n$ is even integer, we have $n = 2j$ where $j \in\mathbb{Z}$,

then $n^2 = 4j^2 \Rightarrow n^2 | 4$, because $n^2$ is divisible by $4$, this is a contradiction; therefore, for every integer $n$, if $n^2$ is even, then $n^2$ is divisible by $4$.

Is my proof valid or can anyone give me hint or suggestion to write a better proof?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't prove this by contradiction, it's silly. $2\mid n^2\to (2\mid n\lor 2\mid n)\to 2^2\mid n^2$ because $2$ is prime.

Comment: Your proof is **valid**! Although a direct proof is easier and arguably more elegant.

Comment: @RobertCardona I think the proof by contraposition is actually the most elegant in this particular instance (see my answer).

Comment: I agree, in this particular instance, proof by contradiction obfuscates rather than clarifies. Unless you've been specifically instructed to do it by contradiction, better to use a different method of proof. I would probably start with $n = 2m$ so $n^2 = 4m^2$...

Answer (score 4):

$$n^2\text{ even }\implies \text{n is even, hence:}$$$$n=2m,m\in\Bbb Z, n^2=4m^2\implies 4|n^2$$

Comment: Also, I generally dislike contradiction proofs(like Mario Carneiro above), they just don't seem as clean to me(in terms of difficulty to follow).

Answer (score 2):

**Proof:** Suppose $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then
$$
n^2\neq [4m = 2(2m)].\;\blacksquare\tag{1}
$$

---

There are really three "core methods" of proof one is likely to use in order to prove your statement: direct, contradiction, and contraposition. You will most often see such a proof proceed directly because this is generally the most natural (i.e., "direct") way of going about it, but let's check out the options:

**Direct:** See the answer provided by @Committingtoachallenge.

**Contradiction:** See your own answer (it's correct, but it could be written up much more neatly).

**Contraposition:** See $(1)$. I'm surprised no one gave this answer because I think it is definitely the easiest / most elegant way of proving it. The idea behind a proof by contraposition is to show that if $n^2$ is not divisible by $4$, then $n^2$ is not even (recall that $p\to q\equiv \neg q\to \neg p$; that is, $\neg q\to\neg p$ *is* the contrapositive of $p\to q$, where these two statements are equivalent. Hence, if we can prove the contrapositive, then we will have proven your original statement.).

Comment: Contraposition is my first idea, but I get stuck at $n^2\ne 2l$ , thanks your work

Comment: I don't think the "contraposition proof" is valid. You wrote "$n^2\ne 4m$, where $m\in\Bbb Z$" - I assume that means $\forall m\in\Bbb Z,n^2\ne 4m$, so far so good.  Then you rewrite this into $\forall m\in\Bbb Z,n^2\ne 2(2m)\implies \forall \ell\in\Bbb Z,n^2\ne 2\ell$, which is not valid (you have only proved this for *even* $\ell$). I think you forgot that this is a $\forall$ not $\exists$ quantifier given the unusual way you wrote it. Note that the same argument would give $4\mid n^2\implies 4^2\mid n^2$ which is false.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I should have just written $n^2\neq 2(2m)$, where $m$ ranges over all of $\mathbb{Z}$, showing that $n^2$ can never be even, despite the value of $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Good spot--I was trying to be cute, but that obviously didn't work. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: @Simple Please see Mario's comment; he noted a flaw in my original argument, where I tried to clean up notation and make things clearer but only muffed it up.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n^2$ is even
and $n^2$ is *not* divisible by $4$.
Then $n^2 = 4k+2$
for some integer $k$.

But every square of an integer is of the form
$4k$ or $4k+1$.
This is the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

A direct proof is more appropriate here. As $n$ is even, we can write $n=2k$ for some integer $k$. Then, $n^2 = (2k)^2 = 4k^2$, which is clearly divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 0):

A proof by contradiction isn't needed, here. Just know that if $n^2$ is even, $n$ is even (easily provable), and that an even number $n$ follows the form $2k$, so $n^2$ is... which is clearly divisible by...

**edit**: Yes, your proof is very much valid.

Comment: Beat ya ;P(by 13 seconds)

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge gah! Well-played (though I believe the OP asked for a hint...)

Comment: Yes I realised that afterwards and I feel ashamed(but it's out there now)

Comment: Unrelated note: I just hit 1000 rep :)

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge Nice! (and what's past is past ;) )